# Como dizer "retrodict" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

*Retrodict*, em inglês, [significa](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/retrodict) inferir algo sobre o passado:

> verb [with object] - State a fact about the past based on inference or deduction, rather than evidence.

Por [exemplo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VFGuupXwng&t=7m23s):

> ... That's all about predicting the future, it's not about retrodicting the past.

Nem o [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-ingles/busca/ingles-portugues-moderno/retrodict/), nem o [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/retrodict) têm tradução para a palavra. A tradução óbvia, "retrodizer", não está no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/retrodizer), nem no [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/retrodizer/). Como traduzir?

Comment: dicionário informal traz retrocitar. Não sei se tem o mesmo significado..

https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/retrocitado/

Comment: Há apenas duas traduções no Linguee, ambas traduzem para retrodizer

https://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/search?source=auto&query=retrodict

Comment: Essa palavra é muito pouco usada. Veja: Did You Know, aqui: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrodict?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld

Comment: @Lambie Onde no "Did You Know" é dito que *retrodict* é pouco usado? Só achei a estatística "Look-up Popularity" de "Bottom 30% of words," que indica que as pessoas buscam pouco a palavra no Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Eu digo que a palavra é pouco usada, como nativa falante de inglês.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu utilizaria retrodizer.

Pesquisando no google, essa é sugestão da Wikipedia

> **Traduzido de inglês** - Retrodição é o ato de fazer uma "previsão" sobre o
>   passado. [Wikipedia (inglês)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrodiction)

Além disso, nesse [artigo da wikipedia sobre Método hipotético-dedutivo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_hipot%C3%A9tico-dedutivo), vemos a referência a **retrodições**.

> Comparação das conclusões com as predições e retrodições

E por fim, cito as duas referências no linguee.

[image: linguee]

Comment: No Google Books encontras bastantes exemplos de "retrodizer" e "retrodição".